# Modify Tufte-book to make first page of each chapter different

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr, tufte, books, fullwidth

I'm a pretty new LaTeX person, so I apologize if this turns out to be a silly question.

I'm working on a class that's a thin modification of `tufte-book` in a few areas.  The one thing I haven't been able to figure out how to do, is that I'd like the first page of each chapter to be full-width rather than have large margin note space.

The `tufte` `fullwidth` environment would require me to manually select the text to go on that page, and that environment also can get sketchy with tables and such.

I thought the best way to do it might be to use the `fancyhdr` package, because the first page of each chapter has a separate style from the others anyway.  But it seems that this would exceed `fancyhdr`'s capabilities.

How should I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a partial solution. Note that the paragraph at the bottom of the first page doesn't get rewrapped when it flows to the second page. This is because TeX doesn't determine where to insert a page break until after it typesets the entire paragraph. There are a few possible options for fixing this problem:

- You can manually trigger a page break by inserting `\clearpage`.
- You could attempt to play with `\parshape`, but that gets finicky. I wouldn't try this until I was done editing the text.
- You could try using a package like [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) which measures the amount of space left on the page, typesets the portion of the paragraph that will fit, then typesets the remainder of the paragraph on the following page. This may interfere with the `\afterpage` macro, though.

Here's an example document:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% Redefine the \chapter macro to use different
% page margins for the first page.
\usepackage{afterpage}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  % Remove the margin notes area
  \newgeometry{%
    width={\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth},
    marginparsep=0pt,
    marginparwidth=0pt,
  }%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  % Restore the margin notes area
  \afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}%
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\geometry{showframe}% visualize the margins

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

% Note how the paragraph at the bottom of the
% first page doesn't rewrap when it flows to
% the second page.
\lipsum[1-8]

\chapter{Second chapter}

% To work around that problem, we can manually
% insert a page break. Hackish, but it works.
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\lipsum[5-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a great start, but it throws-off the margins on the header and footer.  I guess I can work around that by changing the header and footer in page style `plain`.   I'm going to leave the question open, though, in case someone has a solution to the paragraph wrapping problem.  If no-one comes up with a better solution I'll check-mark it.